# Paste into multiple rows and not a single row

Tags: vba, excel

The code below copies data (Associate Entry named range) and pastes it into the particular row number (1RecRow) in a different sheet (AssociateData).

I would like the row to be pasted to all the rows ONLY BELOW the numbered row.

There are a couple of things to bear in mind:
A. The data is filtered and I would like the pasting to affect rows below "1 RecRow" within the filtered view (not ALL - unfiltered - data).
B. If it helps, the data is sorted in a way if the "1 RecRow" is 23, then the next row is 24, 25, 26, 27 (in order).

So manually I would do it in this way: Paste the data in the particular row, copy the data again from 1 RecRow, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow and Paste. I'm just not sure how to adjust the code so that it performs it.

Thanks

```
Sub UpdateLogRecord()

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet

    Dim lRec As Long
    Dim oCol As Long
    Dim lRecRow As Long

    Dim myCopy As Range
    Dim myTest As Range

    Dim lRsp As Long

    Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("AssociateData")
    oCol = 3 'associate info is pasted on data sheet, starting in this column

    'check for duplicate order ID in database
    If inputWks.Range("CheckAssNo") = False Then
      lRsp = MsgBox("Order ID not in database. Add record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "New Order ID")
      If lRsp = vbYes Then
        UpdateLogWorksheet
      Else
        MsgBox "Please select Order ID that is in the database."
      End If

    Else

      'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
      Set myCopy = inputWks.Range("AssociateEntry")

      lRec = inputWks.Range("CurrRec").Value
      lRecRow = lRec + 1

      With inputWks
          Set myTest = myCopy.Offset(0, 2)

          If Application.Count(myTest) > 0 Then
              MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
              Exit Sub
          End If
      End With


      With historyWks
          With .Cells(lRecRow, "A")
              .Value = Now
              .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
          End With
          .Cells(lRecRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName

          myCopy.Copy
          .Cells(lRecRow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
      End With      

      'clear input cells that contain constants
      ClearDataEntry
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: To verify, you want to overwrite all the data from the pasted in each row down to the last utilized row of the sheet?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, within the filtered/currently viewed.

So at the moment I am looking at filtered data and I see C15 to Q27. I would like the data to be pasted in a numbered row (which is already calculated in my code) and paste it down to row 27 (the last row in the filtered data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving this a try... you would specify visible cells to not overwrite the hidden items.

```
Dim LR As Long
    LR = Cells(Sheets("AssociateData").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

      myCopy.Copy
      .Range(Cells(lRecRow, 3), Cells(LR,3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlValues
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

That should paste over the defined range.  I think it would be better than FillDown... which would look like:

```
.Range(Cells(lRecRow, 3),Cells(LR,3)).FillDown
```

If you want to filldown, you would put that in directly after you have pasted the value/formula.

Comment: Cyril, you are a star :)!!!!!!!! I had to add Transpose:=True and it worked! You can't even imagine how much I appreciate your help with it. I've been stuck with it for a day! Have a good rest of the day. I hope to be as good at macros as you are one day!

Comment: Cyril, when I run the macro by clicking F8 on my keyboard, it did work, however, when I run the macro, there is a bug. It highlights the following line:.Range(Cells(lRecRow, 3), Cells(LR, 3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlValues, Transpose:=True and the error says: "Run-time error: 1004. Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. Any idea why?

Comment: I would guess that the DIM needs to happen outside of the "With historyWks", which might be blocking the code I gave you from utilizing the appropriate worksheet?  Move the Dim LR as Long to the top with the other items, leaving the LR = section with the .copy section.

Comment: Hi Cyril
DIM was at the top with other items from the very start. I tried moving LR= to be over and within myCopy.Copy .Range(Cells(lRecRow, 3), Cells(LR, 3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlValues, Transpose:=True
      Application.CutCopyMode = False. However, the same error appears :(. Any more ideas what might cause the bug?

Comment: Try specifying the sheet, since we're not referencing just a cell, as done in your original code.  Sheets("AssociateData").Range(Cells(lRecRow, 3), Cells(LR,3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlValues

Comment: I've changed it but unfortunately it says now that: Application-defined or object-defined error. Is it something to do then the row should be copied again and it doesn't remember what was copied? :( Please help, how come F8 is working and the macro is not :(. Thank you

Comment: Where exactly is the breakdown in that line?  You should be able to cursor over the sections and see a pop-up with more about what VBA thinks it is seeing.  I'm thinking that the range defining with cells is causing the issue.  If the object is having problems, you would need to fine a range like A2:B3 rather than with Cells.

Comment: When I hovered over the yellow highlighted line when using the debugger and when I hovered over lRecRow, in a small yellow window shows "lRecRow=47" which sounds correct as it's the row where it should paste data and a pop up window for LR shows "LR=1". Thanks for your patience @Cyril

Comment: Each part of that line will have it's own information.  Hovering over a section between "." will help narrow down explicitly which parameter is causing the issue.

Comment: Ok, so I hope I am doing it correctly now. The parameters in the debugged row are:
IRecRow=47, LR=1, xlCellTypeVisible=12, xlValues=-4163, True=True, I am also allatching a file on file dropper here: http://www.filedropper.com/formsheeteditopttest2-creatingonemastersheetv8forforumv9v2

Comment: I just tried running the macro in your file and, if I'm looking at the AssociateData sheet, then it runs.  It fails from the Input sheet.  The code that runs on the AssociateData sheet also overwrites everything from Row 1 to the last row (LR as defined).  The Cell reference for starting row is correct, but is causing the object error in the code.  The code appears to lose track of where to start pasting.

Comment: You might be able to do RC format, in the range, to make this work... however I believe Cells() is your downfall.  If I can find more time later to look at this, I can give it a whirl... otherwise if you can try, let me know!

Comment: Hate to say this as a workaround but if you start on the AssociateData sheet.  You can add a line into your code that is     Sheets("AssociateData").Select Just after the Dim section, it works.  Not the perfect answer, but it makes this work, without changing any other code.

Comment: Hello Cyril, thanks very much for looking into it. Because the "Update" button  on the Input sheet is connected to the macro, i looked like it didn't work so sorry I wasn't that accurate. Once I'm back at work on Thursday I will look into it. In the meantime would you be able to clarify what the RC format is? It is so odd as when I ran a code with F8 it seemed to be pasting everything correctly, but I will work on it to get it work. I would be immensely grateful for any suggestions

Comment: I will open my PC now to test it! It is too exciting not to test . You are so helpful Cyril. Thank you

Comment: Yes, so indeed it is now working when I added the Sheets("AssociateData").Select (very impressive something that simple fixed this) and it is copying the data but instead of copying it for the specified row and rows down, it does it for all the rows above the numbered row. You are right. We are so close and still there is something not working.

Comment: I've tried a few things but no luck :(. I'm on training tomorrow at work and will be able to look at it for an hour and then on Thursday I will be back. If you come up with an idea as to how to sort this out I will be grateful. If You are my star today and gave me an idea of how to approach it. @Cyril

Comment: Once I added the line to specify the sheet to look at, I did not have the issue anymore with all rows changing, only the one I was looking at to the bottom of the defined range.

Comment: where exactly did you add the Sheets("AssociateData").Select? I added it just before the second Copy Copy. And when I hit "Update" on the "Input" sheet, it does the rows all above the selected row. So I assume I did not place the Sheets Select command correctly in the code.

Comment: I put it directly after the last Dim line.

Comment: Ok I will try it tomorrow morning. I will use the file I posted and add it after the last Dim line. I keep my fingers crossed it works .Good night and greetings from the UK.

Comment: Just ran it again this morning and looks to work just fine with that position in the code (between Dim LR as Long and Set inputWks=Worksheets("Input")).

Comment: Cyril, you've been so helpful and committed to this question, it is so unusual! Many people would give up on my endless questions and you kept helping me. I can't express how grateful I am. It is working now. I wish you all the very best in the future. Because I have less than 15 reputation I can't add any reputation to your profile but if I can do anything to help let me know. Best wishes.